# Consulta SQL para identificar prestadores disponiveis no horario

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, datetime, matemática

Tenho uma tabela para prestadores de serviço que informa o horario que não estão disponiveis.

```
id_prestador | id_pedido | hora_entrada        | hora_saida
1            | abc1      | 2017-08-10 10:00:00 | 2017-08-10 14:00:00   
2            | xpto2     | 2017-08-10 15:00:00 | 2017-08-10 18:00:00
```

Preciso fazer uma consulta para identificar os prestadores que estão disponiveis no horario pedido, por exemplo:

Horario pedido:
Entrada: 2017-08-10 08:00:00
Saída: 2017-08-10 11:00:00

Nesse exemplo ele iria trazer o prestador 2

Alguma luz?
Muito Obrigado!

Resolvido:

```
SELECT *
FROM fcs_prestadores_pedidos
WHERE hora_entrada not BETWEEN '2017-08-10 16:00:00' AND '2017-08-10 18:00:00'
AND hora_saida not between '2017-08-10 16:00:00' AND '2017-08-10 18:00:00'
```

Comment: Quais já foram suas tentativas?

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo: esse é um caso clássico em SQL: interseção/sobreposição de intervalos. Na web há artigos a respeito; pesquise por `sql interval overlap` ou `sql range overlap` ou termos semelhantes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize a cláusula `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM prestador p
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM prestadores_pedidos pp
                   WHERE pp.id_prestador = p.id
                     AND (pp.hora_entrada BETWEEN '2017-08-10 08:00:00' AND '2017-08-10 11:00:00'
                      OR pp.hora_saida BETWEEN '2017-08-10 08:00:00' AND '2017-08-10 11:00:00'))
```

---

**Observação:** Estou supondo os nomes das tabelas e colunas já que você não informou.

Comment: é uma tabela só prestadores_pedidos
alterei as 2 tabelas pela tabela prestadores_pedidos, mas ele trouxe os 2 resultados

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo você não tem uma tabela só com os prestadores?

Comment: sim, na verdade são 2 tabelas, uma de cadastro dos prestadores que é o prestadores (com id, nome, email, etc) e outra com o registro dos pedidos que é essa aí prestadores_pedidos

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo Alterei a `query` para corresponder a sua estrutura

Comment: ele trouxe os 2 resultados, mas baseado na sua ideia, fiz o seguinte que funcionou: 
SELECT *
FROM fcs_prestadores_pedidos
WHERE hora_entrada not BETWEEN '2017-08-10 16:00:00' AND '2017-08-10 18:00:00'
AND hora_saida not between '2017-08-10 16:00:00' AND '2017-08-10 18:00:00'

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo pense que se você usar diretamente a prestadores_pedido você nunca vai conseguir trazer prestadores que nunca tiveram pedidos

Comment: putz, é verdade. e outra coisa, se o pedido está dentro de um horario indisponivel ele também traz, por exemplo: o prestador A inicia as 15:00 e finaliza as 19:00 e o pedido solicitado foi das 16:00 às 17:00, aí tanto o horario de inicio quanto horario de termino do prestador não estão entre o horario selecionado, entendeu?

Answer (score 2):

Use o operador [between](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) caso você queira verificar um intevalor de uma data

```
where hora_entrada between  @Data1 and @Data2
```

Ou use o operador [AND](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/and.php) para verificar o intervalor entre dois campos da sua tabela.

```
where (hora_entrada >=  2017-08-10 15:00:00 And  hora_saida <= 2017-08-10 18:00:00)
```

Comment: então, na verdade é o contrário, tem que trazer quem não está  entre o intervalo

Comment: Preciso fazer uma consulta para identificar os prestadores que estão disponiveis no horario pedido, por exemplo: não é o que diz sua pergunta

Comment: verdade, vlw, vou alterar a pergunta